# Modifying Views of One Fragment from Another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `SharedPreferences` variable defined in a fragment, which is used in a RecyclerView's adapter class. When the RecyclerView is loaded, a condition is checked inside the `MemeViewHolder` class:

```java
private static final String REWARD_GRANTED_KEY = "reward_granted_nsfw";

if (mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false)) {
    adBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    adBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that this fragment is the second fragment in the list. The first fragment also contains the same code(but has different key for its own). However, the condition in the first fragment is executed immediately since it is loaded at launch. The problem arises with the second fragment because the adapter class is not called until I navigate to that fragment. As a result, the code block mentioned above is not executed. Consequently, when I switch to the second fragment, I initially see the `adBtn` visibility set to `VISIBLE`. Only after scrolling a bit, the condition is finally executed and the visibility is updated based on the value in `SharedPreferences`.

I'm wondering if there is a solution to retrieve the shared preferences from this fragment (`REWARD_GRANTED_KEY`) and use it in the first fragment or in the main activity. With this change, I could modify the condition for the fragment from the activity's perspective:

```java
if (mSharedPrefs.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false)) {
    adBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    adSpace.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    adBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adSpace.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Furthermore, even if I obtain the shared preferences from the first fragment or the main activity, how can I modify the views of the second fragment without actually loading the second fragment initially in the first place?

Could you please suggest a solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be that you will notify recycler view in onResume() method of fragment using notifyDataSetChanged() - see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifydatasetchanged).

Similar but slightly better approach is to listen to SharedPreferences changes using this [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener).

The best approach is to move to for example [Shared View Model](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0) which will need whole rework of your approach.